# ImportError: cannot import name -

Tags: python, django

I have two apps.

- character_api
- relationship_api

`relationship_api` models are little complex. Following model structure gives me `ImportError: cannot import name Character` error after i added `manner` to `character` model.

character_api.models

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from relationship_api.models import RelationshipType

class Manner(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    delayed_types = models.ManyToManyField(RelationshipType)
    allowed_types = models.ManyToManyField(RelationshipType)
    denied_types = models.ManyToManyField(RelationshipType)


class Character(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_created = models.DateField()
    age = models.SmallIntegerField()
    health = models.SmallIntegerField()
    happiness = models.SmallIntegerField()
    depression = models.SmallIntegerField()
    manner = models.ForeignKey(Manner)
```

relationship_api.models

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models
from character_api.models import Character
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class RelationshipType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class RelationEffect(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(RelationshipType)
    effect = models.SmallIntegerField()


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class RelationshipLevel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    type = models.ForeignKey(RelationshipType)
    level_order = models.SmallIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Interact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    available_type = models.ForeignKey(RelationshipType)
    available_level = models.ForeignKey(RelationshipLevel)
    effect_on_level = models.SmallIntegerField()
    other_effects = models.ManyToManyField(RelationEffect)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Interaction(models.Model):
    interact = models.ForeignKey(Interact)
    actor = models.ForeignKey(Character)
    date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pk


class Relation(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(RelationshipType)
    level = models.ForeignKey(RelationshipLevel)
    percentage = models.SmallIntegerField()


class Relationship(models.Model):
    characters = models.ManyToManyField(Character)
    relation = models.OneToOneField(Relation)
    interactions = models.ManyToManyField(Interaction)

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.characters.count() != 2:
            raise ValidationError("There has to be 2 characters for relationship")
        super(Relationship, self).clean(args, kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pk
```

I assume my models are imported properly but complexity of relationship models crashes at some point, but i can't find where it happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Circular import.
Replace your models like this:
`models.ManyToManyField(RelationshipType)` with `models.ManyToManyField('relationship_api.RelationshipType')` and
`models.ForeignKey(Character)` with `models.ForeignKey('character_api.Character')`.
Do not import from models.

Answer (score 2):

You have a circular import.

`character_api.models` contains `from relationship_api.models import RelationshipType` and then `relationship_api.models` contains `from character_api.models import Character`